# add catalog item and category to purchase via transactions api

Tags: square-connect

Im using payment form and square transaction api to retrieve payment but it's showing up uncategorized in square dashboard. Is there an easy way to add the catalog item to the transaction api code i've already written?

can i simply add the link to the new order item under the request_body array?

```
$request_body = array (
 "card_nonce" => $nonce,

)

$txRequest['item_id'] = "my item id";
```

If anyone has a tutorial that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. 
I had to create and Order with the orders api, then pass the order_id to the charge code. In php it looks like this.

```
.......create order here using orders api(code not shown)......

...pass order_id to charge(in php)...
    mix of variables for nonce, etc...
............

$request_body = array (
 "card_nonce" => $nonce,
  "buyer_email_address" => $be,
  "note" => "online Laser Tag reservation",

   "amount_money" => array (
  "amount" => $totalCost,
  "currency" => "USD")

  "order_id" => $my_order_id,

   "idempotency_key" => uniqid()

};

...try/catch statements...
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `CreateOrder` to create an order of items. Then you can pass in the `order_id` to the `Transactions` API (what you will use after the payment form to call the `Charge` endpoint). See here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/transactions/cookbook/itemize-transactions

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The docs say //Set your catalog ID.
$catalogId = '{REPLACE_ME}'; How can i find the catalog ID of an item? Say 'axes'? I know i can use the searchCatalogEndpoint but im using postman and cant seem to get anything but one record of which i'm not searching for. here is my url https://connect.squareup.com/v2/catalog/search

Comment: the docs says..."Once you create an order, you can link it to a transaction." once i create the order how to i pass the order_id  to transactions api. I already have transaction api working right now. In the oders api. i can't find where it generates the order_id